# Why is returning: kotlin.Unit

Tags: kotlin

I cannot understand the reason for returning the result `ef: kotlin.Unit` instead of`_data: {"ndata": "test text"}`
Tell me why I am getting `ef: kotlin.Unit` and how should I do to get`_data: {"ndata": "test text"}`?

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val buttonApi: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.api_test_id)
    buttonApi.setOnClickListener {
        val ef = fuelapi.fuelsend()
        println("ef: $ef")          // ef: kotlin.Unit
    }
}

fun fuelsend() {
    var data = ""
    val httpAsync = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/test"
        .httpGet()
        .responseString { req, res, result ->
            when (result) {
                is Result.Failure -> {
                    val ex = result.getException()
                    println("ex: $ex")
                    data = "err: $ex"
                }
                is Result.Success -> {
                    data = result.get()
                    println("_data: $data")     // _data: {"ndata":"test text"}
                }
            }
        }

    httpAsync.join()
}
```

Comment: function `fuelsend ` isn't returning anything

Comment: How can I get it return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `fuelsend` isn't returning anything. Kotlin function by default returns `Unit`. You need to specify the return type of the function, and return some value from the function body

```
fun fuelsend(): String {
    var data = ""
    val httpAsync = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/test"
        .httpGet()
        .responseString { req, res, result ->
            when (result) {
                is Result.Failure -> {
                    val ex = result.getException()
                    println("ex: $ex")
                    data = "err: $ex"
                }
                is Result.Success -> {
                    data = result.get()
                    println("_data: $data")     // _data: {"ndata":"test text"}
                }
            }
        }

    httpAsync.join()
    return data 
}
```